# Get user data from bearer token web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am implementing .NET Web API 2 in C# using. This works fine, i send the username and password and a bearer token is returned.

Now the token is used for other API calls, but in each call i would like to know the user data. This is because any app could call the web API such as from python code etc, in such cases it will only send bearer token but not user name.

I tried to dig through the code but could not locate it.

Any ideas would be most appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on what type of bearer token you're dealing with.  For example, if this is a jwt token, then it consists of three parts separated by a period: the header, payload, and signature.  To get the user id from the payload, you'll need to base-64 decode the payload and grab the "sub" property.  'sub' is known as a 'claim'.  The token contains many claims but the 'sub' typically stores the user id.  See this for more details:  https://jwt.io/introduction/

In C#, you can parse out the payload of the token using String.Split() and then base 64 decode the payload like this:

```
var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(b64Payload));
```

From there, you just need to deserialize the payload into an object that matches the format you expect:

```
var tokenPayloadObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourJwtObjectHere>(payload);
```

Finally, your user id should be a property of your jwt token object:

```
var userId = tokenPayloadObj.UserId;
```

Comment: i am not using JWT, instead a regular bearer token.